# Query to delete rows from table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:
`datess`, `deletess`, `sample`

I wrote a query like this:

```
DELETE FROM sample
WHERE sample_date_key IN
(SELECT date_key FROM datess WHERE s_date BETWEEN '2015-02-18' and DATE'2015-02-25');
```

But I have 2 rows and two columns in `deletess`:

```
start_date  |  end_date
------------+----------
2015-02-18  | 2015-02-18
2015-01-18  | 2015-01-18
```

I want to delete all the rows in `sample` with dates between `start_date` and `end_date` in `deletess`.

I tried the below code but got error:

> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

```
(SELECT date_key FROM datess WHERE s_date BETWEEN (SELECT start_date FROM deletess) AND (SELECT end_date FROM deletess);
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of the deletess table?  As far as I see it would be the same to just do a join as a sub query?

Comment: `(SELECT date_key FROM datess d INNER JOIN deletess sdel ON d.s_date >= sdel.start_date AND d.s_sate >= sdel.end_date)` Is this the right one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `WHERE EXISTS` to check whether any row match the condition:

```
DELETE FROM sample
WHERE sample_date_key IN
(
  SELECT date_key
  FROM datess 
  WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM deletess
    WHERE s_date BETWEEN start_date
                     AND end_date
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`join` is better than `in`

```
DELETE s
FROM sample s
INNER JOIN datess d
    ON s.sample_date_key = d.date_key
INNER JOIN deletess sd
    ON sd.start_date <= d.s_date
       AND d.s_date <= sd.end_date;
```

Comment: I am getting wrong results.

Comment: could you explain more ?

Comment: My bad! I got the condition wrong. Sorry, it is perfectly right :)